# PHP and SQL not returning correctly

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to pull a three-character string from an SQL database and store it as a session, but it isn't working correctly.

Here is where I request the SQL query and set the session

```
$verified_query = mysql_query("SELECT verified FROM `members` WHERE username = '$myusername'");
$verified = mysql_result($verified_query, 0); // 0 is the index of the field, not the row

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION["verified"] = $verified;
header("location:index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

And here is where I try to get the session:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["myusername"]){
include("./assets/inc/nli-home.inc.php");
}
else {
include("./assets/inc/connect.inc.php"); 
include("./assets/inc/header.inc.php");
if ($_SESSION["verified"] == "no") {
include("./assets/inc/settings.inc.php"); 
}
else {
}
if ($_SESSION["verified"] == "yes") {
    include("./assets/inc/settings-admin.inc.php"); 
}
else {}

include("./assets/inc/header2.inc.php"); 
include("./assets/inc/footer.inc.php");
}
?>
<script>console.log("<?php echo $_SESSION['verified'] ?>");</script>
```

Comment: where is it failing?

Comment: it returns 'yes' for every user instead of 'no' for some.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - undefined variable result notice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$verified = mysql_result($verified_query, 0); // 0 is the index of the field, not the row

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($verified); <- Error was here
```